# my idea - is this proper coding?

Tags: python-3.x

I came up with this idea, which I thought was pretty clever:

```
userinput = ''
while userinput != 'yes':
    userinput= input('Pick first player randomly? (yes/no) ')
    if userinput== 'no':
        break
```

Is that proper 'pythoneese'? And is there a better or 'proper' way of doing this?

Comment: It is more Pythonic to use `while True` vs set string and test. Also, think about case and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite this way:

```
while True:
    userinput=input('Pick first player randomly? (yes/no) ').strip().lower()
    if userinput in ('no', 'yes'):
        handle_user_input(userinput)
        break
```

Comment: This definitely looks a lot better/easier to add more functions. Thanks